# Is it possible to implement property setter explicitly while having a getter publicly available?

Tags: c#, properties, language-features, explicit-implementation

When I define an interface that contains a write-only property:

```
public interface IModuleScreenData
{
    string Name { set; }
}
```

and attempt to (naively) implement it explicitly with an intention for the property to also have a publicly available getter:

```
public class ModuleScreen : IModuleScreenData
{
    string IModuleScreenData.Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I get the following error:

> Error 'IModuleScreenData.Name.get' adds an accessor not found in
>   interface member 'IModuleScreenData.Name'

The error is more or less expected, however, after this alternative syntax:

```
public class ModuleScreen : IModuleScreenData
{
    public string Name { get; IModuleScreenData.set; }
}
```

has failed to compile, I suppose that what I am trying to do is not really possible. Am I right, or is there some secret <strike>sauce</strike> syntax after all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public class ModuleScreen : IModuleScreenData
{
    string IModuleScreenData.Name
    {
        set { Name = value; }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

On a side note, I generally wouldn't recommend set-only properties.  A method may work better to express the intention.

Comment: I agree with the side note, though the other way round - an interface with a read-only property, implemented by a class that makes that property writeable -, for which your solution holds as well, is more acceptable and arguably much more common.

Answer (score -2):

You can't change the how the interface is implemented in the inheriting class. That is the whole point.. if you need to do something new with a property you could make a new property that references the inherited properties specific implementation. Interfaces are there so you can conform to a specified standard for object inheritance.

UPDATE:
On second thought.. you should be able to just do this.... this will compile fine:

```
public class ModuleScreen : IModuleScreenData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating a new property, if possible. Not sure what you mean by changing a way the interface is implemented - I understand that I have to satisfy the contract contained in the interface and explicit implementation certainly is one of the ways to do that.

Comment: See my update.... you should be able to just add the get and satisfy the interface